# $Y = \frac{X_1 X_2}{X_3}$ where $X_i$ is a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, variance, expected-value

$Y = \frac{X_1 X_2}{X_3}$ where $X_i\sim U(0,1)$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are i.i.d

I need to calculate $Var(Y)$ and $Var[Y|X_3=1.7]$

I know that for each $X_i$,

$E[X_i]=\frac{1}{2}$

$Var[X_i]=\frac{1}{12}$

But I'm not shure how to proceed, neither do I know how to calculate the PDF of Y.

¿Tips?

I know that $f_{X_1,X_2, X_3}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = 1 \Bbb1_{(0,1) x (0,1), (0,1)} (x_1, x_2, x_3)$

I thought that since they are independen maybe there were some tricks derived from the expected value, since $E[X_1 X_2] = E[X_1] E[X_2]$

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Well, since the three are i.i.d., $f_{X_1, X_2, X_3}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = 1 for(0,1) x (0,1) x (0,1).$

Comment: As long as you state it.

Comment: @LeslieBrenes when did you mention independence ?

Comment: $X_3=1.7$ is a null event, especially since $X_3$ is supposed to be uniform(0,1).

Comment: $\frac{X_1X_2}{X_3}$ is not $L^1$, therefore $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [answer for the variance of the product of independent random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52699).

With that result, you can easily answer your second question, which is basically $\frac{1}{1.7^2} \mathrm{Var}[X_1 \, X_2]$.

Again using the result in the linked answer, the first question boils down to $\mathrm{Var}[X_1 \, X_2 \, Z_3]$ where $Z_3$ follows an [Inverse uniform distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution). Please note that the variance is infinite in your case (while it would be ok if you had $X_3 \sim U(a,b)$ with $a>0$).